# PYTHON - "Love for Mathematics"

Tags: python, python-3.x, testcase, challenge-response

I just finished a challenge on Dcoder ("Love for Mathematics") using Python. I failed two test-cases, but got one right. I used somewhat of a lower level of Python for the same as I haven't explored more yet, so I'm sorry if it looks a bit too basic.The Challenge reads:

*Students of Dcoder school love Mathematics. They love to read a variety of Mathematics books. To make sure they remain happy, their Mathematics teacher decided to get more books for them. 
A student would become happy if there are at least X Mathematics books in the class and not more than Y books because they know "All work and no play makes Jack a dull boy".The teacher wants to buy a minimum number of books to make the maximum number of students happy.*

**The Input**

The first line of input contains an integer N indicating the number of students in the class. This is followed up by N lines where every line contains two integers X and Y respectively.

```
#Sample Input
5
3 6
1 6
7 11
2 15
5 8
```

**The Output**

Output two space-separated integers that denote the minimum number of mathematics books required and the maximum number of happy students.

*Explanation:* The teacher could buy 5 books and keep student 1, 2, 4 and 5 happy.

```
#Sample Output
5 4
```

*Constraints:
1 <= N <= 10000
1 <= X, Y <= 10^9*

---

***My code:***

```
n = int(input())
l = []
mi = []
ma = []
for i in range(n):
  x, y = input().split()
  mi.append(int(x))
  ma.append(int(y))
  if i == 0:
    h=ma[0]
  else:
    if ma[i]>h:
      h=ma[i]

for i in range(h):
  c = 0
  for j in range(len(mi)):
    if ma[j]>=i and mi[j]<=i:
      c+=1
  l.append(c)
great = max(l)
for i in range(1,len(l)+1):
  if l[i]==great:
    print(i,l[i])
    break
```

---

***My Approach:***
I first assigned the two minimum and maximum variables to two different lists - one containing the minimum values, and the other, the maximum. Then I created a loop that processes all numbers from 0 to the maximum possible value of the list containing maximum values and increasing the count for each no. by 1 every time it lies within the favorable range of students.
In this specific case, I got that count list to be (for the above given input):
`[1,2,3,3,4,4,3,3,2 ...]` and so on. So I could finalize that 4 would be the maximum no. of students and that the first index of 4 in the list would be the minimum no. of textbooks required. 
But only 1 test-case worked and two failed. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me out here.
Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem is alike [minimum platform problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-platforms-required-railwaybus-station/).

In that, you need to sort the min and max maths books array in ascending order respectively. Try to understand the problem from the above link (platform problem) then this will be a piece of cake.

Here is your solution:

```
n = int(input())
min_books = []
max_books = []
for i in range(n):
  x, y = input().split()
  min_books.append(int(x))
  max_books.append(int(y))

min_books.sort()
max_books.sort()

happy_st_result = 1
happy_st = 1
books_needed = min_books[0]

i = 1
j = 0
while (i < n and j < n): 
  if (min_books[i] <= max_books[j]): 
    happy_st+= 1
    i+= 1

  elif (min_books[i] > max_books[j]): 
    happy_st-= 1
    j+= 1

  if happy_st > happy_st_result:
    happy_st_result = happy_st
    books_needed = min_books[i-1]

print(books_needed, happy_st_result)
```

Try this, and let me know if you need any clarification.

Comment: that was a nice way to do it, and it worked too! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

@Vinay Gupta's logic and explanation is correct. If you think on those lines, the answer should become immediately clear to you.

I have implemented the same logic in my code below, except using fewer lines and cool in-built python functions.

```
# python 3.7.1
import itertools

d = {}
for _ in range(int(input())):
    x, y = map(int, input().strip().split())

    d.setdefault(x, [0, 0])[0] += 1
    d.setdefault(y, [0, 0])[1] += 1

a = list(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[0]))
vals = list(itertools.accumulate(list(map(lambda x: x[1][0] - x[1][1], a))))

print(a[vals.index(max(vals))][0], max(vals))
```

The above answer got accepted in Dcoder too.

Comment: that worked too! thanks!, but may I know the use of the underscore - "_" in the initialization of the for loop?

Comment: @rev0 - to understand the purpose of underscore, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python)